# How do I change the starting position of this draw method in python?

Tags: python, position, draw, turtle-graphics

This code draws a few letters using turtle graphics:

```
import turtle
turtle.speed(1)
myWin = turtle.Screen()

turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(260)
turtle.left(55)
turtle.forward(-60)
turtle.right(55)    
turtle.forward(-60)
turtle.right(55)
turtle.forward(-60)
turtle.left(100)
turtle.forward(-60)
turtle.right(45)    
turtle.forward(-60)
turtle.right(55)
turtle.forward(-50)
turtle.right(35)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(260)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(50)
turtle.forward(-200)
turtle.right(130)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(45)
turtle.forward(260)

myWin.exitonclick()
```

The problem is it starts drawing in the middle of the screen and I want it to start at the far left side. Is there any way to change the initial position

Comment: possible duplicate of [python turtle set startpos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713037/python-turtle-set-startpos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `turtle.penup` to pick up the pen and move to the position you want, and then do `turtle.pendown`

Comment: I can't seem to use it right. Do you just say turtle.penup(position) and then turtle.pendown(position)

Comment: do a `turtle.forward(10);turtle.penup();turtle.forward(10);turtle.pendown();turtle.forward(10)` and see what happens.

Comment: That didn't change the starting position (well it didn't seem to do anything) but what is it supposed to do?

Comment: `penup()` will move the pen up. When you move (like `forward(100)` it will move the pen without drawing anything). Then when you have moved to the position you like, you can do a `pendown()`. So you can do `penup()` and then go to the corner, and then `pendown()`

Comment: Are you using iPython? Its better if you just try commands interactively first.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the turtle interface is a coordinate grid.
so you can use the `goto(x, y)` function

```
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(300,200)
turtle.pendown()
```