# Python turtle start position

Tags: python

So here is the thing,
im drawing Westminster Palace for my personal project at school,
I have already done all the drawing but there is one problem that is making my life a lot harder,
I want to create a line of windows in the shortest way so I came up with this:

```
from turtle import*
for row in range(1):
    for col in range(1,8,2):
        penup()
        setpos(col*50, row*50)
        pendown()
        for i in range(4):
            fd(50)
            lt(90)
```

it does draw 4 windows in a row just like I would like to, but the problem is that it always starts in the starting position(0,0) and
I would like to get it to start drawing at (-335,-195) but I just cant figure out how
I would be gratefull if someone would help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python turtle set start position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713037/python-turtle-set-start-position)

Comment: [turtle doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/turtle.html)

Comment: The answers given below are exact duplicates of the 2nd answer in the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add before the `for` loop:

```
penup()
goto(-335,195)
pendown()
```

Also there is no point in `for row in range(1)`.  You can just define `row = 1` instead of having triple nested loops.

Comment: yes i tried that but because of how my setpos(x,y) is written it will come back to the beginning

Comment: oh i found the solution in setpos(col*50, row*50) i just imported the number where i want it to go so it looks like this(col*50-335, row*50-195), thanks for the tip with row ;)