# Draw a pixel at specific x,y coordinates

Tags: python, draw, pixel, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm using Turtle Graphics, and i want to draw a pixel at specific x,y position

something like :

```
pixel = turtle.Turtle()
pixel.draw(x, y)
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713037/python-turtle-set-start-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [`goto`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.goto), [`setpos`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setpos) and [`setposition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setposition) methods of the turtle module can be
  used to set the position to a given x, y for the turtle.
- Then, the [`dot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.dot) method can be used to draw a pixel at the point.

---

```
# STEP-1: GOING TO (X, Y)
# Any one of these methods can be used
# pixel.goto(x, y) # or
# pixel.setpos(x, y) # or
pixel.setposition(x, y)

# STEP-2: DRAWING A PIXEL
pixel.dot(1, "black") # drawing the pixel.
```

Further, a function can be defined incase the same has to be used multiple times like so -:

```
def draw_pixel(turtle, x, y, color) :
    # Draws a pixel of given color using given turtle at (x, y)
    
    # Any one of these methods can be used
    # turtle.goto(x, y) # or
    # turtle.setpos(x, y) # or
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.dot(1, color) # drawing the pixel.
    return
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted, thanks again !